# I'm use PHPExcel in laravel project for export excel file with chart on local it working but on hostinger Chart only not display

Tags: laravel, phpexcel

I'm use PHPExcel in laravel project for export excel file with chart on local it working but on hostinger Chart only not display

**This my controller for generate chart in excel file**

```
        $dataSeriesLabels = array(
        new \PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', 'Worksheetdata!$B$1', 
        NULL, 1), 

        );
        $xAxisTickValues = array(
        new \PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', 
        'Worksheetdata!$A$2:$A$32', NULL, 31),
        );
        $dataSeriesValues = array(
        new \PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('Number', 
        'Worksheetdata!$B$2:$B$32', NULL, 31),
        );
        $series = new \PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries(
        \PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::TYPE_BARCHART, // plotType
        \PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::GROUPING_CLUSTERED, // plotGrouping
        range(0, count($dataSeriesValues)-1), // plotOrder
        $dataSeriesLabels, // plotLabel
        $xAxisTickValues, // plotCategory
        $dataSeriesValues // plotValues
        );
        $series- 
        >setPlotDirection(\PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::DIRECTION_COLUMN);

                        $plotArea = new \PHPExcel_Chart_PlotArea(NULL, 
        array($series));
                        $legend = new \PHPExcel_Chart_Legend('Date');
                        $month = Input::get('Monthly');
                $m = date('F', strtotime('2012-' . $month . '-01'));
                        $title = new \PHPExcel_Chart_Title('Data of '.$m);
                        $xAxisLabel = new \PHPExcel_Chart_Title('Energy 
        (kwh)');
                        $yAxisLabel = new \PHPExcel_Chart_Title('Date');
                        //    Create the chart
                        $chart = new \PHPExcel_Chart(
                            'chart1',       // name
                            $title,         // title
                            $legend,        // legend
                            $plotArea,      // plotArea
                            true,           // plotVisibleOnly
                            0,              // displayBlanksAs
                            $yAxisLabel  ,   // yAxisLabel
                            $xAxisLabel     // yAxisLabel
                        );

                        //    Set the position where the chart should appear 
            in the worksheet
                        $chart->setTopLeftPosition('B27');
                        $chart->setBottomRightPosition('L42');

                        //    Add the chart to the worksheet
                        $sheet->addChart($chart);
                    });
                });
                $excel->export('xlsx');

            }
```

**this code is one of all controller**

**This file export on local**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMF3l.png)
**This file export on hostinger**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8Fjg.png)

**Spec**
laravel 5.4
php 7.2 
Apache/2.4

thank for help.

Comment: We need more clarification on this. Are you receiving an error? What is the actual result?

Comment: Result is this picture in post and when this function working it not error

Comment: have you checked the depencies of the library?

Comment: @abr In this controller i have other function this use same library but this work such as  "PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing" but  function about chart not work